# Read XML file in Jess rule engine

Tags: rule-engine, jess

Can anyone help me out to read XML file in Jess rule engine? I've just stared working with this rule engine so don't have that much idea.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to spend the next few months of your life writing an XML parser in Jess, have a look at JAXB. (Maybe my tutorial helps a little: https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

You will then have a set of Java classes, and you'll have to write the corresponding deftemplates.

You can devise an algorithm, walking the object tree resulting from XML unmarshalling, and insert the objects resulting from XML elements as facts.

Most of this can and should be done in Java. Come back again for help on the deftemplate and/or insertion and/or rule authoring - when you have some code samples to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much..I'm trying your solution. @laune